# Let $R$ be a ring with unity and $N$ be an ideal containing a unity, then $N = R$

Tags: proof-verification, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring with unity and $N$ be an ideal containing a unit $u$. Then $N = R$.

This is a really simple statement, but I want to know if my short argument works. So in this context let $R$ be the ring and $N$ be the ideal (this means $aNb \subset N$ for all $a,b \in R$)

Since $N \subset R$, show the other inclusion. Let $r \in R$, then $r1 = ruu^{-1} \in (ru)N \subset N$. So both inclusion holds.

Comment: Note that in your proof only the existence of *some* unit $u$ in $N$ was needed to show $R \subset N$, not *all* units.  Of course a posteriori you have shown that ideal $N$ contains not only all units, but actually all the ring elements of $R$.

Comment: @hardmath, but $u$ was chosen arbitrary.

Comment: I'm not criticizing the proof as insufficient.  I'm saying the hypothesis is "overkill" because you only need assume an ideal contains one unit (not all of them) to conclude the ideal "blows up" (becomes all of $R$).  BTW, your problem is stated in the title, and not clearly framed in the body of the Question.  This should be avoided, so Readers have a self-contained body to study.